# How to consider the example of a word's usage 'repeating' its own meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was to put this question months back but was not getting a proper example. Now, I have one in my hand!

I had observed it many times that dictionaries give examples of *words' usages.* But at times, they *repeat* the meaning of the word that the word already talks about.

The simplest example is that I often tell my students that you should not add *about* after *discuss.* Consider that *about* is already included in *discuss.* So, *Let's discuss the proejct* and not *Let's discuss about the project.*

Well, but today, I was going through the samples of *draught* and the original question popped up in my mind!

> [draught](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/draught_1?q=draught): [countable] a flow of ***cool*** ***air*** in a room or other confined space

Then, the example follows...

> A ***cold draught of air*** blew in from the open window.

Indeed, it's redundant! Why mention *'cold'*; why mention *'air'* when you **already** have in the definition.

In my opinion, the sample should be like...

> A draught blew in from the open window.

Why? Because just like *discuss includes 'about'*, *draught* includes *cold* and *air* both.

Question: How to take these samples? And based on this, how to take those all examples that *repeat* the meaning of the words that they have already in their definition!

Comment: Not every seeming redundancy is a pleonasm. Sometimes repetition of an idea adds emphasis. Besides, *cool* is not necessarily *cold*. And a draught (AmE: *draft*) *may* be cool but does not have to be, despite what your one citation suggests.

Comment: @Robusto you mean *cold air* in this context is different from *cool air?* Enlighten me please.

Comment: I don't think a [*draught*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/draught) has to be cool/cold, though it is usually used that way. It has more to do with unintended air movement rather than temperature. Also according to the word origin, it is "related to draw".

Comment: @user3169 the question is *if* the usage sentence repeats the *meaning* of the word, how to take it? Is that fine?

Comment: Collins defines draught as  as: 
*A draught is a current of air that comes into a place in an undesirable way.* as in - 


*On a cold day there can be quite a draught from the letterbox.* Though drought is often associated with cold air, stressing the low, uncomfortable temperature   of a drought using other  adjectives adds more flavor to the sentence.

Comment: And indeed _draught_ is used also referring to hot air: *He loves the light touch of the muzzle as they lift the carrots with their lips and **the hot draught of breath** against his hand.* https://books.google.it/books?id=pRcgAQAAIAAJ&q=%22hot+draught+of%22&dq=%22hot+draught+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh_8CD7ZPcAhWvhaYKHVyjAwgQ6AEITjAI - *Kites flew from the concrete ledges, catching **the hot draught of air** from the town as it passed over the estate and up the ...*

Comment: So you would object to **a flow of hot lava** or **hot molten lava**?

Comment: @MaulikV: You really don't get how *cool* and *cold* are relative qualities?